# Flow Screen Input Lookup Component - Unexpected Error when retrieving "Case" layout information

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, permissions, sharing

I have a lookup component that is apart of a screen flow that allows users to search for existing account records. All users have access to read and edit access to this field via permission sets and it exists on the page layout.

I also have modify all and access to all fields for read and edit on the account object.

Below is the exact error users are seeing:

[image]

I also have the lookup on the page layout of the case object as seen here. On the page layout it is read only at the moment.

[image]

Comment: Hi Matthew, would you be able to show some of the code here? The only thing I can see right now is that it looks like we're trying to use a Case layout for a Person Account, which could be causing that error.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich I am using the minimum salesforce profile and using permission sets for giving users access to the system. I think the issue is in the permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the user profile as a Page Layout Assignment for the object your lookup field is looking to.
I had a similar issue with a lookup on OpportunityContactRole and turns out only the System Admin had a proper Page Layout Assignment for that object.

That resolved my issue.